# Python: Can you use a single line to pass enumerate into a function?

Tags: python, enumerate

As a thought experiment I had to ask myself (and obviously you), because of the frequency with which I have to type these two lines. Can it be condensed into one line?

I have various classes that have functions. Objects of these classes inevitably end-up in lists. I frequently have to call a function for each item of the list using an enumerated value. Is there a clean one line solution? Or just stick with the tried and true?

```
for choice, action in enumerate(availableActions, 1):
     action.show(choice)
```

I tried some list comprehension to no avail.

Comment: I hate to state the obvious but `for choice, action in enumerate(availableActions, 1): action.show(choice)` is just one line...?

Comment: I'd just stick with this. Anything else clever you do will just convolute the simple logic. If you're finding you're doing this pattern a lot, you could just wrap it in a function and pass the collection in.

Comment: Yes, this code is as clean and readable as it could be.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis Wow. I actually didn't now, that you didn't have to indent the for loop. You learn something new every day.

Comment: @kaya3 yeah indeed. I was more dubious about the fact that the enumeration skipped the first item, because it doesn't relate to the question asked.

Comment: @DrewAschenbrener I think it's frowned upon in the PEP style guides for reducing readability, but it works! :-)

Comment: The enumeration does not skip the first item; it simply numbers them from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: To be clear, `[action.show(choice) for choice, action in enumerate(availableActions, 1)]` would call each method as intended, but also create (then immediately discard) a list full of values for no reason. Don't use a list comprehension when you don't care about the list it creates, just to save a line of code.

Comment: Can you create a function which takes `availableActions` as the parameter, or does calling the `.show()` method vary also?

Comment: Your for-loop is perfectly Pythonic. Don't try to write everything on a single line.